# Run-time error9. Subscript out of range error

Tags: excel, vba, subscript

I am using a code to search other sheets in the same workbook for particular text this option works well on my system however does not work on a different one. Can anyone assist me why.
This is on excel and VBA was used to create the macros and Below is the code

```vb
Sub Search_Macro()
'
' Search Macro
'
    Dim Sheet_Name As String
    Dim Search_string As String
    Dim Rng As Range
    
    Sheet_string = 0
    
    
    Sheet_Name = Sheets("Summary").Range("O23").Value
    Sheet_string = Sheets("Summary").Range("O27").Value
    
    If Sheet_string = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Select correct Product and Topic", vbOKOnly
             
        Exit Sub
    End If
                 
                              
    Sheets(Sheet_Name).Select
    Set Rng = Range("A1:Z500").Find(Sheet_string)

    If Rng Is Nothing Then
        Sheets("Summary").Select
        MsgBox "Select correct Product and Topic", vbOKOnly
    Else
        Cells.Find(What:=Sheet_string, After:=Range("A1"), _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas2, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have a sheet called Summary, and do you have a sheet called whatever you put in O23?

Comment: The code which i have, works on my system. so i thought it may not be in regards to the sheet name or topic being searched. And i am not referring to any other excel using this code. When i am running this macro on my system it works however it is giving the error" Run-time error9. Subscript out of range error" on one system outside my environment since we are using VDIs. Outside the VDI it does not work.

Comment: You realize that the contents of the cell O23 can change while this code stays that same?

Comment: Yes. i am creating this as a knowledge base for new employyes. the subject and topic is selected by the new employees from a drop down list that happens in those cells. and i have to go to the particular product in seperate sheet and then search for the topic.

Comment: O23 and O27 are basically options in drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a shot into dark, since no info of what type of error you get on the other system, but I would guess you perhaps either misspelled the sheet name in you input cell O23 or the position of the input cell has changed and the macro code get the content of a different cell.

Be especially careful about spaces vs. underscores in the sheet names, spaces before and after the sheet name. It happens a lot :)

Comment: The code which i have, works on my system. so i thought it may not be in regards to the sheet name or topic being searched.